# Detecting clicks and releases of ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a conflict between a `ScrollView` and a `ViewPager`.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
If user clicks ViewPager:
   Disable ScrollView

If user releases ViewPager:
   Enable ScrollView
```

I've already got the disable/enable code working, but I can't get the click/release code working.

I've tried using `OnTouch`, as so..

```
pager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            scroller.setScrollingEnabled(false);
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            scroller.setScrollingEnabled(true);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

..but this seems to disable the ViewPager from scrolling left and right. Am I using it wrong?

Is there any other alternative to detect presses and releases? Also I'm trying to get it to work on Android 2.1 and higher, so `OnDrag` doesn't seem compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of the return value for OnTouch()-method to the OnTouchListener interface:

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

[OnTouchListener documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Try to return true only for Action of type ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP, false otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Missed that. Returning true on those actions would override the ViewPager's built in controls and cause it to behave wrong, but returning false on everything works like a charm.